Retrieve model initial position after translation
I've followed this question in order to apply an translation to a model in the viewer.
Translate a model after load (move origin)
Let's say that I want to apply multiple translation in different times to my model.
How can I go back to the model initial position ? Is this information stored somewhere ?
Thanks you all !

To go back to the initial position, you can use the same logic explained in the other Stack Overflow post, and simply set the offset to (0,0,0):
// ...

    const position = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    fragProxy.position = position;

// ...

